# How to set each indivdual student answer into a seperate colour

Tags: php

I have a set of answers and student answers. What I want to do is that for each question, if an individual student answer matches an individual answer, then display the individual student answer in green, if an individual student answer is not in the answer, then display that individual student answer in red.

For example:

So for example:

```
Answer: B,C
Student Answer: B,D
```

The output of the above should display student answer B as green as it matches with answer B but student answer D should be red as there is no D in answer. But with the current code it is displaying both student answers in red.

How to solve this issue?

Code below:

```
        if($questionData['answer'] == $questionData['studentanswer'])
{
    echo '<td width="30%" class="studentanswer green"><strong>'.htmlspecialchars($questionData['studentanswer']).'</strong></td>' . PHP_EOL;
    $check = true;
}
else
{
    echo '<td width="30%" class="studentanswer red"><strong>'.htmlspecialchars($questionData['studentanswer']).'</strong></td>' . PHP_EOL;
    $check = false;
}
```

UPDATE:

Doing the following for the above example:

```
print $questionData['answer'];
print $questionData['studentanswer'];
```

I get this output:

```
B,CB,D
```

Comment: More information preferably in the form of a short, self-contained example is required, see http://sscce.org/

Comment: You are currently comparing the complete answer string "B C" with "B D". Try to [`explode`](http://php.net/explode) the strings and compare them one by one.

Comment: @hsan Will need help with writing the explode statement.

Comment: @user2048994 have a look at the linked reference and give it a try. If you are stuck edit your question and ask about the specific problem that you encountered.

Comment: @hsan Yeah im doing that now :)

Comment: @user2048994, can we see the CSS class `.red` and `.green`?

Comment: @Jueecy In CSS .red contains `color: red;` and .green contains `color: green;`

Comment: @user2048994, are you absolutely sure about that?

Comment: @user2048994, could you print the `$questionData['answer']` and `$questionData['studentanswer']` values that you are testing?

Comment: Real Answer and student answer will be in sequence or not. Like Real answer 'B D' and student answer may be like 'D B' or it will also be 'B D'. if it will be in sequence then you can directly match them or give more detail about it.

Comment: @nbhatti2001 The answers are already displayed in sequence

Comment: @Jueecy Yes I am sure on that, I will print $questionData['answer'] and $questionData['studentanswer'], give me 5 mins

Comment: @Jueecy I included update displaying the prints

Comment: Could you put an `echo '<br>';` between the two prints?

Comment: @Jueecy Yes I can put a break inbetween, this makes it `B,C` (break) `B,D`

Comment: Haven't you said there were 2 student answers? Where is the second couple of answers?

Comment: @Jueecy I think the string 'B,D' was a string with the 2 student's answers actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$questionData['answer'];` is a string with the content 'B,C'. Therefore, you should compare only part of the string. In the same way, `$questionData['studentanswer']` is also a string. You can explode them and then compare the values member by member. This should do the trick.

```
$RealAn = explode (',', $questionData['answer']);
$StudedntAn = explode (',', $questionData['studentanswer']);

// This error is from the way $questionData['answer'] is formatted.
// 'D,A,,C' should also work but 'D, A,B,C' won't
if (count($RealAn) != count($StudedntAn))
  echo "There was a problem with your answers.";

// Apparently you only want a row of the table with all the results, outside the loop
echo '<td width="30%" class="studentanswer"><strong>';

// Initialize the checking parameter as not null (so it's safe to use it later)
$check = TRUE;

// Iterate for as many array members as there is
for ($i = 0; $i < count ($StudentAn); $i++)
  {
  // Save what kind this particular member is
  $class = ($RealAn[$i] == $StudentAn[$i]) ? 'green' : 'red';

  // Display each member with the color previously associated to it
  echo '<span class = "' . $class . '">' . htmlspecialchars($StudentAn[$i]) . '</span>';

  if ($i != count($StudentAn)-1)
    echo ', ';

  // If only one of the members is not the same, $check will be false
  if ($class == 'red')
    $check = FALSE;
  }

echo '</strong></td>';
```

Comment: 2 questions, one it gives me a warning stating cannot use a scalar value in an array and that is pointing at the lines where it displays the `$check[$i]`. Other question is I only want `$check[$i] = true` only to occur if the full `$StudentAn` matches the full `$RealAn`, not part of it. If part of it or fully incorrect then `$check[$i] is false`. But how can that be done?

Comment: I changed the code, deleting the $check. Do you use it later (thus need it) or it's only for this little piece of code? Depending on the use I'd suggest another way of doing it. I will change it now for the last question.

Comment: Done, I had no idea how $check was intended to be used. Hope it works

Comment: Hi, that is great, just one little issue, after last answer it display a comma for example A,C,D, How can I remove comma after last answer?

Comment: These small bugs I always forget... fixed (;

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  <head>
  <style>
          .red{color:red;}
          .green{color:green;}
  </style>
  </head>

<?php
  echo GetAns("B D C","B C D F");

function GetAns($ans,$stuAns)
{
    $arr_ans=explode(" ", $ans);
    $arr_stu_ans=explode(" ",$stuAns);
    $str="";
    for($cnt=0;$cnt<count($arr_stu_ans);$cnt++)
    {
        $stu_ans= $arr_stu_ans[$cnt];
        if(in_array($stu_ans,$arr_ans))
            $class="green";
        else
            $class="red";
        $str.="<span class='$class'> $stu_ans </span> ";
    }
    return $str  ;


}

?>
```